# Cohomology of a countable directed union of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, group-cohomology

It's puzzled me for a long time why two arguments in group cohomology look connected but no immediate visible connection is available. First, it is a theorem that if a group $G$ is the union of a chain $G_0\le G_1\le \dots G_n\to\dots$ of subgroups $(G_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ then the cohomological dimension $\mathrm{cd}(G)$ of $G$ is at most $1$ greater than $\sup_n\mathrm{cd}(G_n)$. This result can be proved by using the chain of subgroups to define a tree with an action of $G$: there results a Mayer-Vietoris sequence and various homological corollaries. On the other hand there is a theorem in Gruenberg's *"Notes on group cohomology"* that the same conclusion about $G$ can be drawn if the sequence of groups $G_0\to G_1\to G_2\to\dots$ is connected by maps that are not necessarily injective. The Mayer–Vietoris sequence is not available, and there is no useful action on a tree. For example, consider the Baumslag–Solitar group
$\mathrm{BS}(2,3)=\langle x,y;\ y^{-1}x^2y=x^3\rangle$, and the chain in which each map is the map determined by $x\mapsto x^6$ and $y\mapsto y$. Gruenberg's theorem then correctly predicts that the cohomological dimension of the colimit $G$ is $\le 3$ (in fact it is $3$) but without an action on a tree there is no easy way of proving that the dimension *is* $3$ (which is a result of Gildenhuys and Strebel) without using additional methods.

> Is this a territory where $\infty$-categories can bring a way of connecting Gruenberg's point of view and the Mayer–Vietoris sequence point of view? Is there a connection with this mo question: [Mayer-Vietoris sequence in group cohomology for arbitrary pushout squares of groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429146/mayer-vietoris-sequence-in-group-cohomology-for-arbitrary-pushout-squares-of-gro)

Comment: Don't these results follow immediately from Milnor's exact sequence for the cohomology of the homotopy colimit of the classifying spaces of the sequences of groups?

Comment: @GustavoGranja Very possibly. Please could you give a reference?

Comment: The Milnor sequence is described in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book Theorem 3F.8. The homotopy colimit of a sequence of spaces or mapping telescope is described between examples 3F.2 and 3F.3

Comment: Applying the Milnor sequence to the Baumslag-Solitar group mentioned in the question gives $H^3(G,M)\cong\lim^1H^2(BS(2,3),M)$ for any $G$-module $M$ where $G$ is the largest metabelian quotient of $BS(2,3)$ which is a valuable point of view but not quite the tree-action inspired view I suspect might be out there.

Comment: Perhaps it’s worth pointing out that Hatcher’s proof of the Milner sequence uses Mayer—Vietoris. In general, anywhere there’s Mayer—Vietoris, there’s secretly a tree lurking.

Comment: Let me expand on that a little. Hatcher’s proof uses a mapping telescope $T$. This has a natural structure as a graph of spaces. The graph-of-spaces structure lifts to a graph-of-spaces structure for the universal cover $\widetilde{T}$. The underlying graph  of $\widetilde{T}$ must be simply connected, hence a tree. I think this is the tree that you want!

Comment: So perhaps the moral is that you don’t need $\infty$-categories, but it is a good idea in this case to think about graphs of spaces rather than graphs of groups! Still, there is an algebraic construction of the tree — the injectivity assumption isn’t actually used to construct the Bass—Serre tree, only to prove that it’s non-trivial in interesting cases.

Comment: The mapping telescope $T$ that HJRW mentions is aspherical in both cases, so it is a classifying space for the direct limit group.  The asphericity of the mapping telescope doesn't rely on the injectivity, and the dimension of the mapping telescope is one more than the sup of the dimensions of the pieces.  (Proof that the mapping telescope is aspherical: any sphere is contained in a finite subtelescope, this finite subtelescope retracts onto its last space and that space is aspherical.)